# How does IcoMoon choose the code point for a newly added symbol, and can I change it?

Tags: fonts, icons, icon-fonts

I'm using the IcoMoon app to generate an icon font for a web app - there's a number of developers on the team; we share the project file so anyone can add a symbol to the font.

Apart from a bunch of symbols in the basic latin area, everything in the font is in the unicode private use area starting at `e600`, with the last symbol at code point `e65e`. However when I add a new symbol it appears at `e34e` by default.

I'm just wondering how that was chosen, and if I can change it so that the next symbol will be added at `e65f`, then `e660` etc - so all the symbols in the generated font will be at adjacent code points.

(It's easy to change the code when exporting the font, but I want to minimize the number of manual steps for other developers on the project.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code may come from different sources. It may come from the set you're selecting from. Some icon sets come with their own default codes. The code may also come from what was previously assigned to a previously selected icon. In general, there is no explicit way to control the default code.

Not sure if it would help, but you could use the "Reset" button in the "Generate Font" tab to reset the codes of some or all the selected glyphs.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. I don't think the "Reset" button will help in this specific project because I need to keep some symbols in basic latin area (for the time being, for backwards compatibility) while adding new symbols to PUA. Thanks for the explanation anyway.